# Meaning of "inspecting the truce" in this context

Tags: dialogue

No matter how many times I watch the [SWOR trailer "Return"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pb8M5P1QKX8&t=46s), I can't grasp this interaction:

> -*Bounty hunter peeks at a what seems to be an attractive female.*
>
> +Eyes front.
>
> -Just inspecting the truce, corporal.

Am I just hearing the word "*truce*" wrong? (i.e., is it another word?) The word truce seems very absurd, downright nonsense in this context- I have checked the 'Tureng dictionary' to find a sense that fits, but I can't find anything. Perhaps it's a slang usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think he says:

> Just inspecting the ***troops** /tɹuːps/*, corporal!

The ***p*** is almost inaudible, but it is there.

Comment: He is saying troops, no doubt about it.